# Interface, abstract class or something else?

Tags: java

If I have 2 Conventional and Scientific classes, how should their implementation look like? Namely, I mean that in the Conventional class there will be methods such as: addiition, subtraction, multiplication, division.

But also in the Scientific class there will be these methods but, the difference will be that in the Scientific class there will be additional methods, responsible e.g. for 
returning the remainder of division, etc.

I have several variants, but I don't know which one is the most suitable:

1) Creating the abstract Calculator class, which will contain common abstract methods, e.g. addition, subtraction, division, multiplication and member variables, then Conventional and Scientific classes would inherit the Calculator class. In addition, the Conventional class would implement its own additional methods. However, this solution does not make sense, because e.g. the addition method will have an identical implementation in the Conventional and Scientific classes.

```
abstract class Calculator {

    protected BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    protected BigDecimal currentNumber;
    protected String chainOfAllNumbers = "";

    abstract public void addition(double number);
    abstract public void subtraction(double number);
    abstract public void multiplication(double number);
    abstract public void division(double number);
}

class Conventional extends Calculator {

    @Override
    public void addition(double number) {

        currentNumber = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
        result = result.add(currentNumber);
    }  

    @Override
    public void subtraction(double number) {

        currentNumber = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
        result = result.subtract(currentNumber);   
    }

    @Override
    public void multiplication(double number) {

        currentNumber = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
        result = result.multiply(currentNumber);   
    }

    @Override
    public void division(double number) {

        currentNumber = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
        result = result.divide(currentNumber);   
    } 
}

class Scientific extends Calculator {

     @Override
    public void addition(double number) {

        currentNumber = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
        result = result.add(currentNumber);
    }  

    @Override
    public void subtraction(double number) {

        currentNumber = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
        result = result.subtract(currentNumber);   
    }

    @Override
    public void multiplication(double number) {

        currentNumber = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
        result = result.multiply(currentNumber);   
    }

    @Override
    public void division(double number) {

        currentNumber = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
        result = result.divide(currentNumber);   
    }

    //In addition, implementation of own methods

}
```

2) Creating the abstract class Calculator, which will contain common methods, e.g. addition, subtraction, division, multiplication and member variables, but with the implementation of these methods, because the implementation, e.g. addition, will be identical in both cases. Then Conventional and Scientific would inherit the Calculator class. In addition, the Scientific class would have its own methods. This seems to be a pretty good solution, but an empty conventional class looks strange, I don't know if this can be the case and is this a desirable mechanism?

```
abstract class Calculator {

    protected BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    protected BigDecimal currentNumber;
    protected String chainOfAllNumbers = "";

    public void addition(double number) {

        currentNumber = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
        result = result.add(currentNumber);
    }  

    public void subtraction(double number) {

        currentNumber = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
        result = result.subtract(currentNumber);   
    }

    public void multiplication(double number) {

        currentNumber = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
        result = result.multiply(currentNumber);   
    }

    public void division(double number) {

        currentNumber = BigDecimal.valueOf(number);
        result = result.divide(currentNumber);   
    } 
}

class Conventional extends Calculator {


}

class Scientific extends Calculator {

    //In addition, implementation of own methods

}
```

3) Creating an interface with common abstract methods that would be implemented by conventional and scientific classes. Then create a second interface that would have abstract methods and would only be implemented by the Scientific class. But this solution does not make sense, because the implementation of some methods, e.g. the addition would be identical.

```
interface Operations {

    abstract public void addition(double number);
    abstract public void subtraction(double number);
    abstract public void multiplication(double number);
    abstract public void division(double number);
}



interface additionalOperations {

    abstract public int mod();
}
```

Or maybe some other way would be definitely better?

Comment: I think you have a basic misconception of what Interfaces and abstract classes are. If your scientific calculator "is-a" normal calculator + some additional functions, then you'd write 1 implementation and have 2 interfaces: ConventionalCalc and ScientificCalc, where ScientificCalc extends ConventionalCalc. The implementing class then implements both Interfaces. That way you have the same code and visibility of functions is bound to the interface in use.

Comment: Fildor, 
From your statement, I conclude that I should create one implementation of the Calculator class, and two ConventionalCal and ScientificCal interfaces. Then, depending on the needs, I would create, for example, an object of the Calulator class and assign it to a reference variable of the type ConventionalCal or ScientificCal depending on which method I would need to call? 
Am I right?

Comment: Exactly. In this case that would be the easiest method to avoid duplicate code.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Calculator` class should not be instantiated, make it `abstract`. That's a good decision. But that doesn't mean you also have to make it's methods `abstract`. So Approach **2)** would be the best one. But this doesn't solve your other problem:

> This seems to be a pretty good solution, but an empty conventional class looks strange, I don't know if this can be the case and is this a desirable mechanism?

If `Conventional` isn't different from `Calculator` why have both? Make `Conventional` a regular class with all the methods of the former (now redundant) `Calculator` class, and extend `Conventional` in `Scientific`.

If you *want* to have an interface `Calculator` that dictates all different Calculators to have at least these basic methods, then make one and implement it in above classes.

**EDIT:** This would lead to the following overall structure (which is a **suggestion** - there sure are numerous other ways to do this, especially because i don't know the exact context these classes/interfaces will live in):

```
public interface Calculator {
    void addition(double number);
    void subtraction(double number);
    void multiplication(double number);
    void division(double number);
}
```

```
public class ConventionalCalc implements Calculator {

    @Override
    public void addition(double number) {
        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void subtraction(double number) {
        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void multiplication(double number) {
        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void division(double number) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

```
public class ScientificCalc extends ConventionalCalc {

    public void someScientificMethod(double number) {
        // TODO
    }

    public void anotherScientificMethod(double number) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

This way, every type of calculator will either have to implement the interface `Calculator` directly (if it wants to handle things differently then `ConventionalCalc`), or it can just extend `ConventionalCalc` (which is the more likely version, i guess).

Comment: I would like to have interfaces, so from your statement I conclude that I should create one implementation of the Calculator class, and two ConventionalCal and ScientificCal interfaces, which would extend the ConventionalCal interface. Then the Calculator class would implement both interfaces and, depending on the needs, I would create, for example, an object of the Calulator class and assign it to a reference variable of the type ConventionalCal or ScientificCal depending on what method I would call? 
Am I right?

Comment: No, you got that wrong. Let me add an explanation... Just a second....